# Android Studio 2021.1.1.23 "app:debugCompileClasspath"

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, compiler-errors

so guys i'm trying to launch my Android App , and that error face me.

ERROR : " **Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.**
"

build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://jitpack.oi'}


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*build.gradle(Module)*

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.learn"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //for support screens

    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'

    //Rounded imageView
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'

    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.1.1'

    //MultiDex
    implementation 'android.multidex:mutidex:2.0.1'
}
```

can any one help me.I was looking for a solution All day.

Comment: Have you tried to use `com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.1` together with `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore`? Does it work that way?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `'android.multidex:mutidex:2.0.1'` to `'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'` like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    
    //MultiDex
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy  its worked  .... I didn't notice the Error .you saved me .